# Watch only wallet

Tags: private-key, watch-only

I'm having this message:
"Your wallet does not have private key for this address. You cannot spend coins received unless you have the private key elsewhere."

How can I move my coins from watch only account to account with the private key?
P.S. I am using Mycelium Wallet App.

Thank you in advance,
Milan

Comment: definition of a watch only wallet: An address or pubkey script stored in the wallet without the corresponding private key, allowing the wallet to watch for outputs but not spend them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to recover private key?,](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84215/i-need-to-recover-private-key)

Answer (score 1):

You can't spend bitcoin from a watch only address unless you have the corresponding private key which generated that address.

Comment: Yes, I believe I have it... I mean, I have two accounts, one of them has the private key and the other one doesn't... Could be that it's the same private key? Thanks

Comment: What dates were the addresses generated on?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how can I find out the date of generation? I'm pretty new in this. Thank you for your time

Comment: When you start Mycelium, is there a 'Cold Storage' option?

Comment: Yes, there is. But, I can't find any date there

Comment: I asked for dates because of the possibility of your private key being encode in an older WIF. You should be able to import your private key in the Cold Storage section of Mycelium.

Answer (score 0):

To receive the bitcoins originally you should have had a “key pair” meaning a public and private key pair. Online wallets automatically generate the private key with your public address. *Imported* public addresses to your wallet will be a “watch” address that won’t allow you to spend your bitcoin if you don’t import your private key. If you import your private key to your wallet it will no longer be a watch address and you can spend your bitcoin. Just import your private key for your public address and you should have full control to transact.