# How to transfer from watch only wallet

Tags: blockchain.info

What is the real and legit name of the app that I can use to transfer tokens from watch only wallet?

Comment: A watch-only wallet is a type of wallet that allows you to monitor the balance and transaction history of a particular address(es) without having access to the private keys. This means you can't spend or transfer funds from a watch-only wallet directly. You need to have access to the original wallet that holds the private keys associated with the address you're monitoring. If you don't have access to the private keys, you won't be able to transfer funds from a watch-only wallet. This seems to be a duplicate to following question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/67253/87158

Answer (score 2):

There is none. A "watch only wallet" lets you *watch* tokens that are not yours. Only the owner of the tokens who created the address and knows the private key can transfer the tokens.